# What file in flask contains "127.0.0.1 - - [date] "[method] [path] HTTP/1.1" status code "

Tags: python, flask

When you run flask, it returns the status code at the end. Something like this...

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jan/2019 19:47:31] "POST /file/wh HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I'm trying to locate what file that originates from. Is there an easy way to find out?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the [logging configuration](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/) and add a `%(filename)s` in there somewhere.  However, it's probably still not going to point at what you want.  This is likely being logged in a top-level handler.  What is it that you are really trying to find out?

Comment: I agree with @JohnSzakmeister. But if you are interested in seeing the actual code which prints those lines, I think you are looking for this: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/cli.py#L830.

Comment: @TimKlein, Yes I was looking for the actual code. I was mainly curious to know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: @TimKlein I don't think that's generating the log message.  rose: what WSGI server are you using?  It's likely the thing logging the requests.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Sorry I'm relatively new to all this. What do you mean by  "WSGI server"?

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I think I got it now. I'm using Werkzeug. The log statement was in Werkzeug/serving.py. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep,Werkzeug would be the WSGI server and that's it in serving.py.  Good job!